# gulp elixir-typescript failed to compile

Tags: laravel, angular, typescript, gulp, laravel-elixir

I'm trying to use Angular2 with laravel 5.2 so I'm trying to configure gulp to compile typescript file.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "elixir-typescript": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is my tsconfig.json (that I put into resources/assets/typescript):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and at the end I have my gulpfile.js:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var elixirTypscript = require('elixir-typescript');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');

    mix.typescript('main.ts', 'public/js/');

    mix.copy('node_modules/@angular', 'public/js/angular');
    mix.copy('node_modules/when/es6-shim', 'public/js/es6-shim');
    mix.copy('node_modules/es6-promise', 'public/js/es6-promise');
    mix.copy('node_modules/rxjs', 'public/js/rxjs');
    mix.copy('node_modules/systemjs', 'public/js/systemjs');
    mix.copy('node_modules/zone.js', 'public/js/zone.js');

});
```

When I start gulp from console I get a lot of errors, such as:

```
/var/www/chat/laravel/node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(81,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[14:59:24] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] TypeScript Compilation Failed!: /var/www/chat/laravel/node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(81,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
{ [TypeScript error: /var/www/chat/laravel/node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(81,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.]
  name: 'TypeScript error',
.....
```

It seems that it tries to compile all the typescript stuff in node_modules. I used the field "exclude" in tsconfig.json but it doesn't seem work.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue but fixed it here.

https://github.com/axiskafi/angular2-laravel5

your package.json and gulp file needs some modification. Follow the given link and instruction, it will solve your problem.